# How to return Connection to oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, ucp

I have an application which uses `oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource` to maintain pool of JDBC connections. I am able to get a connection and use it.

At the end of my function, I want to return the `connection` to the pool. I don't find any method to return the the pool.

How to return the connection to the pool?

Comment: That should be the usual `connection.close()`. At least that's the standard way to signal to the pool that the client is done using the connection.

Answer (score 3):

The fine manual [oracle.ucp.jdbc
Class PoolDataSourceImpl](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12826/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSourceImpl.html)

> This DataSource uses the Universal Connection Pool to get a connection, creating a proxy to that connection, and returning the proxy to the client. When the client calls close on the connection proxy, the underlying physical connection is returned to the pool.

So, as noted in the comments, use `connection.close()`. The connection is a proxy and the close method will return the connection to the pool instead of closing the connection as is usual.